# Drupal modules - Nice menus CPU usage and response time

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I am having a problem with nice menus drupal module. It's the module that is consuming more web server time and it's the slowest to respond . This is weird for me as a so insignificant module can cause this response time problems. Nice menus also seems to consume a lot of CPU and is creating problems on a scalability point of view.

The drupal version I am using is -> Drupal 6.22

I want to know if any of you had this problem and if yes how to resolve it .

Thanks

Comment: How do you detect that the nice menu is causing the cpu usage increase? I use it regularly and it works well

Comment: I have new relic and it`s the module that consumes more resources which is weird